# Knockout.js binding css/js libraries in header

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Is it possible, to bind links and scripts(css/js) with knockout?

I tried to bind it like:

```
<!-- ko text: headerLibs -->
<!--/ko -->
```

But it is just text. Property headerLibs can contain from 0 to 10 different libs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have an array of script URLs and wish to add tags for them to the DOM dynamically. Try:

```
<!-- ko foreach: headerLibs -->
  <script type="application/javascript" data-bind="attr: { src: $data }"></script>
<!-- /ko -->
```

If on the other hand `headerLibs` already contains the markup for the `<script>` tags, try the [`html:`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html) binding instead:

```
<div data-bind="html: headerLibs"></div>
```

Note that I am using a `<div>` instead of a virtual element - as far as I know, the `html` binding does not work with them.

Comment: I have just ko.observable(), where is list of <link> or <script> with sources. Is it possible, to not make an array from this list?

Comment: @AndreyMykhaylov the second solution works with a single observable instead of on observable array.